# Crystal - Split string based on carriage return

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a field like this, where I only want the first/latest entry to show on the Crystal report:

05/01/2018 00:00:00 pm notes

04/01/2018 00:00:00 pm more notes

03/01/2018 00:00:00 pm even more notes

Here's the code I have been trying to work with, but I get an error of "a subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array." Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

```
stringvar array csl;
stringvar return;
csl:=split({table.field},chr(13));
//csl[1]
if isnull({table.field}) then return:= ""
else return:=csl[1];
return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is presumably because the check for null happens after the `split`.

I usually try to avoid using arrays/variables in Crystal Reports. Mainly because you can't group or use aggregate functions on formulas that contain variables.

So here's a solution that works with string-functions:

**First Entry**

```
If InStr({table.field}, chr(13)) > 0 Then
    Left({table.field}, InStr({table.field}, chr(13)))
Else
    {table.field}
```

**Last Entry**

```
If InStrRev({table.field}, chr(13)) > 0 Then
    Right({table.field}, Len({table.field}) - InStrRev({table.field}, chr(13)))
Else
    {table.field}
```

---

### **EDIT**

To get the second line too you have to do the `InStr`/`InStrRev` two times:

**First Entry**

```
If InStr(InStr({@table.field}, chr(13))+1,{@table.field}, chr(13)) > 0 Then
    Left({@table.field}, InStr(InStr({@table.field}, chr(13))+1, {@table.field}, chr(13)))
Else
    {@table.field}
```

**Last Entry**

```
If InStrRev({@table.field}, chr(13), InStrRev({@table.field}, chr(13))+1) > 0 Then
    Right({@table.field}, Len({@table.field}) - InStrRev({@table.field}, chr(13),InStrRev({@table.field}, chr(13))-1))
Else
    {@table.field}
```

Comment: Mat, you are awesome and this works perfectly! But, I messed up. Apparently the entries have date, time on the first line, then notes on the next line, so i actually need the next line as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you SO much! Works just how i need it, I have accepted your answer.